# Entrar sin contraseña al usuario root mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, root

Llevo rato buscando problemas similares pero no he encontrado solución, así que abro post.
Resulta que estaba realizado un mysqldump de mi base de datos mysql en windows 10 con el usuario root y no solo no ha creado el .sql si no que aparte de fallar ahora me falla el acceso mediante root a mysql.

A la hora de intentar crear el .sql he puesto lo siguiente, dando como resultado un .sql vacio y un mensaje de acceso denegado y permisos insuficientes.

```
mysqldump -u root -p ocio > C:\prueba.sql
```

Ahora a la hora de acceder a root con las credenciales correctas obtengo este mensaje de error:

```
.\mysql.exe -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Nota: el mensaje del error a la hora del dump no lo tengo ya que cerré powershell y no esperaba ningún error con root a la hora de logear después. Decir también que las credenciales de root son 100% correctas y la única operación desde poder hacer login a no es el comando dicho de dump.
He intentado hacer flush privileges desde otro usuario, pero no tengo privilegios suficientes.

Lo ultimo que he intentado es introducir skip-grant-tables en el my.ini de C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 para acceder sin contraseña y restaurar privilegios pero no hay manera:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

¿Cuál seria la manera correcta de acceder sin root y restaurar privilegios? Dispongo de acceso físico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución a mi caso ha sido resetear root, para ello tenia que deshabilitar la contraseña de root. He creado un my.ini(mysql-init.txt) en D:, he parado el servicio mysql80 y he introducido el siguiente comando en C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\

```
mysqld --defaults-file"=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --init-file=D:\\mysql-init.txt
```

Donde le indico el my.ini por default y le digo el nuevo que he creado.

Seguidamente, he restaurado el servicio ,después he entrado con la nueva contraseña establecida en mi mysql-init.txt y por último después de recuperar root con los cambios pertinentes he eliminado el .txt que he creado.

Contenido del mysql-init.txt:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

Espero que le pueda servir a alguien que tenga problemas con root en mysql windows, un saludo!!